# How to handle high traffic when Redis cache is cleared?

Tags: node.js, caching, redis, next.js

I'm using below line of code to cache data into Redis on my NextJS website. However, the Redis cache expires in 5 minutes.

```
const getFromCache = async (key, getter) => {
    const cached = JSON.parse(await redisGetKey(key))
    if (cached) {
        return cached
    } else {
        const data = await getter() // Getter function could be any database call to get data
        redisSetEx(key, 5 * 60, JSON.stringify(data))
        return data
    }
}
```

How to handle a situation in which Redis cache does not exist and we get a huge number of requests within a second? Currently, in that case, all those requests find Redis cache empty and are sent to the database which is causing a lot of database calls & choking the entire network causing a lot of Gateway Timeout errors.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the XFetch algorithm: [Optimal Probabilistic Cache Stampede Prevention](https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/%7Eavattani/papers/cache_stampede.pdf), which do probabilistic early expirations.

```
function XFetch(key, ttl; β = 1)
    value, ∆, expiry ← CacheRead(key)
    if !value or Time() − ∆β log(rand()) ≥ expiry then
        start ← Time()
        value ← RecomputeValue()
        ∆ ← Time() – start CacheWrite(key, (value, ∆), ttl)
    end
    return value
end
```

It does probabilistic recomputing the value before the key expires. Check the paper for detail.

**Another Solution**

If you know which keys are the hottest ones, you can have an extra thread/process, which does the computation, i.e. `redisGetKey`, and update the value and TTL before the key expires. So that the hottest keys never expire.